# I can't select the “Intel” Prime profile in the NVIDIA-settings

Tags: intel-graphics, nvidia-prime, nvidia-geforce

I'm on a pretty fresh ubuntu installation on a laptop with intel integrated GPU and NVIDIA dedicated GPU. I spent the last day figuring out how to install the NVIDIA drivers and make them run, and now I'm at the point where I can finally see all the entries in nvidia-settings and linux is supposedly running entirely on the Nvidia GPU.

Now I should be able to select at any point the prime profile "Intel" to switch back to the integrated graphics and save some energy. For some reason, however, the "button" used to select the intel profile is greyed and cannot be selected.

Any Ideas? I've looked around for a couple of hours, but couldn't find the exact same problem anywhere.

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375




$ prime-select query
nvidia




$ LANG=C sudo prime-select intel
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-375', 'nvidia-375']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-375', 'nvidia-375']
Info: selecting nvidia-375-prime for the intel profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-375-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) in manual mode
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: And what does `prime-select query` and `sudo prime-select intel` show?

Comment: Main post edited with the results. I hope the Italian messages aren't too much of a problem.

Comment: It is interesting that `nvidia-prime` does not see the Intel adapter. I do not know the solution. I can read some Italian (studied it long ago) but for other people you could run that command as `LANG=C sudo prime-select intel` it will output in English.

Comment: I suspect that you installed the driver some unconventional way. It is quite easy, nothing to spend a day on. And as the result you broke Nvidia Prime.

Comment: I rebooted after entering `sudo prime-select intel` and right after the grub the fans of the GPU went on a frenzy and the laptop froze completely. I had to shut it down using the power button.
Do you think I should purge eveything about nvidia and install the driver again from the beginning?

Comment: How did you initially install the driver?

Comment: I tried many different guides that i found, with no success. The last one, which worked, is this one: http://my30daysoflinux.blogspot.it/2015/10/installing-nvidia-gtx-950-drivers-in.html?m=1

The only thing I did differently is removing `nomodeset` from `/etc/default/grub` at the end, so I wouldn't get my resolution locked to 720x480.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? I suggest a fresh install of Ubuntu and installing the drivers from the repos without downloading anything and fiddling with blacklists. You need 1 command to install the drivers: `sudo apt install nvidia-375` if you are using 16.04, or 17.04.

Comment: sudo prime-select intel  worked fine for me. But my laptop came per-installed with Ubuntu20.04(OEM version) and Nvidia drivers. So I wonder why it was greyed out when I wanted to switch back to Intel since OEM versions are well tested. But that CMD works. So thanks

Answer (score 2):

run below command and restart

`sudo prime-select intel`

Comment: Is it safe to forcefully select intel even tho the interface grays it out? I mean, there must be an explaination on why they don't want you to select it :-/. If only they verbos-ed it...